# The certificate authority is not trusted, in android webview but works fine in mobile browser

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-webview

I have to open a website inside a webview, I got error certificate auhtority un-trusted, but when I open the same web inside mobile browser it works fine,
and I don't want to show a dialog inside onReceivedSslError handler.proceed

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `handler.proceed()` in `onReceivedSslError` method of web view client.

Comment: if we do that we need to display a dialog to proceed if the app is distributed through play store, my point is why its working on browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and ended up adding the certificate explicitly as described here:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingAdditionalCas